# Quasi Perfect number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

An integer n is called quasi perfect  if $\sigma (n)=2n+1$ where $\sigma$ is sum of divisors function. It is not known whether there are any quasi perfect numbers. My question is are there any interesting consequences if there are or aren't any such numbers of this form?